# LocalStorage showing undefined after setitem

Tags: angular, local-storage

I am storing items on localstorage when doing authentication user. Upon storing the items are undefined when checking in localstorage

In my service file :-

```
import { Result } from '../models/user';
dt: number = new Date().getTime();
 
  loginForm(data: any): Observable<any> {
   return this.http
  .post(`${environment.baseUrl}/api/login`, data, this.httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
  }

  setUser(resp: Result) {
    localStorage.setItem('username', JSON.stringify(resp.UserName));
    localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(resp.BearerToken));
    localStorage.setItem('lastVisit', String(this.dt));
    localStorage.setItem('storeids', JSON.stringify(resp.StoreIds));
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
```

model:-

```
export interface Result {
    UserName: string;
    StoreIds: string;
    BearerToken: string;
}

export interface RootObject {
    IsSuccess: boolean;
    ErrorMsg: string;
    ErrorCode?: any;
    Result: Result[];
}
```

Where am I going wrong ?

**EDIT:-**

*Component login :-*

```
login() {
    if (this.myGroup.valid) {
      this.authService.loginForm(this.myGroup.value).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.IsSuccess == true) {
          console.log(response);
          this.authService.setUser(response);
        }
      }, error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
    } else {
      alert("error ! login failed");
    }
  }
```

In login what changes have to be done ? error in `setUser (response)` as `Argument of type 'RootObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Result'.`

Comment: you forget to pass the requested data to setUser(). Please see @MichaelD answer.

Comment: @VirenderThakur I have mentioned the error now I am facing in his answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where exactly is the `setUser()` function called? Ideally it would be called in the `tap` operator (to store the details in local storage as a side-effect) piped to the HTTP request.

```js
loginForm(data: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(
    `${environment.baseUrl}/api/login`, 
    data, 
    this.httpOptions
  ).pipe(
    tap((resp: Result) => this.setUser(resp)),
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

#### Update: types

Given that the response is of type `RootObject` and not `Result`, the types have to changed the following way

```js
loginForm(data: any): Observable<RootObject> {  // <-- Observable of type `RootObject`
  return this.http.post<RootObject>(
    `${environment.baseUrl}/api/login`, 
    data,
    this.httpOptions
  ).pipe(
    tap((resp: RootObject) => this.setUser(resp.Result[0] as Result)),
    retry(2),
    catchError(this.handleError)
  );
}
```

Now we are sending the first element of the `Result` array. But why is it an array if the response would only contain one element? That perhaps must be adjusted in the backend to return an object instead of an array.

Comment: Its throwing error -  `Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Result': UserName, StoreIds, BearerToken`

Comment: @NoobCoder: Are you sure the response from the HTTP request adheres to the `Result` interface defined? If so try asserting the type: Change `return this.http.post(...)` to `return this.http.post<Result>(...)`.

Comment: @NoobCoder Angular is written with TypeScript. The fundamental selling point is types, so you should use them (i.e. not `any`). This includes specifying the type argument for `http.post`

Comment: @MichaelD Yes did that but I am facing issue after that in login component. In login method inside  if condition I am getting `Property 'IsSuccess' does not exist on type 'Result'`. I have added the json response in EDIT section on my question

Comment: @MichaelD since `IsSuccess` is in `RootObject` interface model, how can I sole this issue ?

Comment: @Clashsoft I got it. I have changed as suggested by Michael

Comment: @NoobCoder: You answered the question yourselves. The `IsSuccess` property is in `RootObject`, but seemingly (and wrongfully) declaring the type as `Result` instead. Please change the type there to `RootObject`.

Comment: @MichaelD what about `setUser(resp: Result)` function param? This should be result only ?

Comment: @MichaelD In your updated solution I am getting this error `Type 'OperatorFunction<unknown, unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<RootObject>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more` .Also I cannot change the backend since it's already in prod. Is my model is right ?

Comment: @NoobCoder: This is too much guess work now. Try to create a Stackblitz with mock data.

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks for the updated solution. It is working now. I just had to remove `this.authService.setUser(response);` from login component as you have already suggested to pass in `tap`.